# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32connsole'

Tags: python, youtube, keylogger

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python-advanced-keylogger-crash-course-master\keylogger.py", line 103, in <module>
    send_email(keys_information, file_path + extend + keys_information, toaddr)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python-advanced-keylogger-crash-course-master\keylogger.py", line 79, in send_email
    attachment = open(attachment, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\python-advanced-keylogger-crash-course-master\\key_log.txt'
```

Comment: The error message is clear: the `key_log.txt` file does not exist.  What is your actual question?

Comment: The title appears unrelated to the problem - That's not a `ModuleNotFoundError`. From the title, the problem would be a misspelling of `win32console`.

Answer (score 0):

try instead this:
`import win32con`

Answer (score 0):

````
import pygame
from gtts import gTTS

def speak (Text_to_speak):
    with io.BitesIO() as file:
        gTTs(text=text_to_speak, lang='en').write_to_fp(file)
        file.seek(0)
        
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            continue
            
            
if __name__  == "__main__":
    text = str(input("what would you like me to say?: "))
    speak(text)```
````

Comment: pygame 2.0.0.dev8 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/python/sound.py", line 18, in <module>
    text = str(input("what would you like me to say?: "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line